# how to delete tenant admins that were not created properly?

Tags: kaa

I am running kaa 0.10.0 on ubuntu 14. Since the outgoing email was not properly configured, I created many tenant admins. Is there a way to delete them?

[image]

I do not see the delete button as the doc http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Administration+UI+guide
shows.

Thanks for help.

James

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no option for the Kaa 0.10.0 release to delete a tenant admin. The documentation you referenced is for Kaa 0.9.0 (and prior) only. The Kaa 0.10.0 documenation is available [here](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Welcome/).

Also, please note the user types defined in Kaa. For example, to add, modify (or delete if that option is available) a tenant admin, you should sign in as Kaa administrator.

Answer (score 0):

james800,

I suppose what you're referring to is "deleting tenant" instead of "deleting tenant admin"? If you're referring to deleting tenant admin, you can have a delete button after clicking on one of the tenant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually meant to delete users of tenant admin role  created by kaa admin. The problem is that they were created when my out-going email service was not properly configured. When I click on such tenant admin, a new page shows up, but there is no delete button. See the screen shot https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6schhtoxn2jqw8/deleteTenantAdmin.JPG?dl=0

Comment: That `tenant admin` you clicked on, is actually a tenant.
From the screenshot you provided on dropbox, there isn't any users in the tenant yet. Are you sure you're trying to remove a tenant admin, not a tenant?
Here's a screenshot where I have a tenant `Demo Tenant`, with a tenant admin `admin` in it --- https://i.imgur.com/DYNtxtO.png

Comment: btw, I have no idea how to remove a tenant :(